# What are some sounds that interest you?

Tags: sound-effects, recording, survey

And I'm not talking about sounds that hold some special memory, or that evoke a certain sensation. I go through little phases every now and then where I want to explore a particular type of sound fairly heavily. My latest one is electronics and the interference patterns they induce. Every once in a while I get the recorder out and see what I can find where I'm at. It's amazing how they vary so much in characteristics. I've found some interesting ones at home this week; I've posted a few on my website if you're interested at all (http://www.dynamicinterference.com/2010/07/23/electronic-interference/).

Anyone else go through these little phases? If so, what are some of the sounds you've gone after?

Comment: Cool sounds Shaun! Lots of great nuggets in there. How did you mic them up?

Comment: @Steve Urban - With an $8 unbalanced "Recorder Telephone Pickup" from Radio Shack, running into a $500 dollar Sony PCM-D50. I love the absurdity of that combination.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a thing for sounds in the kitchen recently. Everything from dripping water, to frying pans, to tapping the side of a fresh smoothie for a ridiculously deep bass sound.

Answer (score 2):

I love noises that you can make with your mouth. Being a foley artist, I have worked quite hard over the years to perfect sfx generated from fluctuating my mouth and Larynx. The main problem is that it can sound like it is coming from the mouth so I just work on eliminating this factor through practice. I did a dog over the weekend for a film and the recordist loved it so much that we decided not to tell the director until after he had heard the sound. I can hardly wait to find out what happens and how he responds.

I also like body falls and punches. Has taken me years to get it perfect but I think I am there.

Answer (score 2):

The clicks and catches of different washing machines. Pretty mundane, but very cool, and very sequenced.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have developed a thing for tubes at the minute. Created a really cool atmos buy recording a small fan through a long cardboard tube, add on tons of reverb and you've got a huge droning scary atmos. Used it a lot recently from Evil Lair's to rural thatched cottages.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I definitely get obsessed with different sounds.  For a while, I was obsessed with firecrackers and bottle rockets.  I still love recording that stuff, but it gets expensive...

I'm currently obsessed with two things - binaural recording and recording my own Impulse Responses.  I have a ton of stuff on my blog on my binaural stuff.  Nothing on IRs yet, but I plan to put that up soon too.

I'm also a big fan of large metal hits.  I work in a building with a ton of large sheet metal surfaces that make awesome sounds when you hit them really hard.  I try to do this when nobody is around, since people think I'm crazy ...

Comment: Have you ever tried "worldizing" an IR - like playing back the tones at 4X or higher and recording the tones 4X or higher and thus making your IR humongous?

Comment: Indeed I have.  Love that stuff.  It get's quite tricky though, since I generally use Logic's IR Utility, which is mostly automated.  Tricky trying to get it to understand what I'm trying to do...  Haven't quite nailed it down that way.  Work in progress...

I hope to start building a decent IR library to sell sort of like a sound library before too long.